# Algorith to remove elements from array one by one based on index

Tags: arrays, algorithm

**This is a simplification to the purest case of a problem in a embedded system with arbitrary limits that i cannot control**

Let there be an array of anything, for example words:

`["apple", "pear", "banana", "orange"]`

Let there be an array of indexes (starting at one) to remove items from:

`[1,3]`

We need a function that returns the result of removing those indexes from the starting array, in this example the result should be:

`["pear", "orange"]`

as it removed indexes `1` and `3`

However, the only accepted operation to achieve that is a function that removes one item by index from the array, and mutates it, for example:

We have the original array `["apple", "pear", "banana", "orange"]`
We want to remove items `[1,3]`
We `removeItem(1)`
The result is `["pear", "banana", "orange"]`

The next item we want to remove is the item at index `3` of the **original** array, which is `"banana"`, however, the item at **current** index `3` is `"orange"`, thus, the naive approach to remove items does not work, as it will result in removing `"orange"` instead, with a final result of:

`["pear", "banana"]` instead of `["pear", "orange"]`

Comment: Are the indices sorted?

Comment: @NicoSchertler i can sort them, the only limit is the way to interact with the array

Comment: what programming language do you need?

Comment: Index starts from 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the indices are sorted, then you simply need to decrease the index by one each time you remove an element:

```
for i = 1 .. len(indices)
    elements.removeItem(indices[i] - i + 1)
```

Alternatively, delete the items backwards. This is probably also more efficient depending on the implementation of the removal process:

```
for i = len(indices) .. 1
    elements.removeItem(indices[i])
```